# From algebraic form to parametric form with second degree equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to convert the following equation from an algebraic form: $\begin{cases}x^2+y^2=1\\z=1\end{cases}$ to a parametric form. I did: $$\begin{cases}x=\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}\\z=1\end{cases} \rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1 & 0 & 0 & \pm\sqrt{1-y^2} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\end{array}\right]\rightarrow \begin{cases}x=\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}\\y=t\\z=1\end{cases}$$
Then, how do I get to the form $X=X_P + X_G$, where $X_P$ is the particular solution and $X_G$ is the general solution?

Comment: It is $$x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Comment: Edited, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it algebraically like that, but more often than not, when you see equations of the form $x^2 + y^2 = k$ for some random $k \in \mathbb{R}$, you should think of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions. In this case, the parameterization $\Phi(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, 1)$ with $0 \leq t < 2 \pi$ works perfectly fine.